# Улучшить семантику html кода

Tags: html5, семантика

Как в приведенном ниже коде можно улучшить семантику?

Вижу, может можно где-то "р" использовать, или нет? что еще?

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header">
                <img src="./logo.png" alt="logo" width="23" height="3" class="header__logo" />
            </header>
            <main class="content" role="main">
                <div class="title content__title">
                    <div class="title__caption">
                        <h1 hidden="hidden">Document</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <div class="info-main__caption">
                        <h3 hidden="hidden">Main information</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info__fields fields">
                        <div class="fields__name">
                            <label for="name" class="formfields__label-name">Name</label>
                            <div class="fields__div-name">
                                <input id="name" type="text" maxlength="12" pattern="[^0-9`~!@#$%*+=?]" title=":)"
                                 placeholder="Амвросий" value="Анатолій" class="fields__input-name" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="fields__year">
                            <label for="year" class="fields__label-year">Year</label>
                            <div class="fields__div-year">
                                <input id="year" type="number" maxlength="4" pattern="(?:10|30)[0-9]{2}" title="1000 - 3000"
                                 placeholder="1310" value="1907" class="fields__input-year" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="color content__color">
                    <h3 class="scolor__title">Select colors</h3>
                    <div class="color__hint">Check only available</div>
                    <div class="color__prefs">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="colors__item1">
                                <input id="red" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="red" checked="checked" class="colors__red"
                                />
                                <label for="red">red</label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="colors__item2">
                                <input id="green" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="green" checked="checked" class="colors__green" />
                                <label for="green">green</label>
                            </li>
                            <li class="colors__item3">
                                <input id="blue" type="checkbox" name="colors" value="blue" checked="checked" class="colors__blue" />
                                <label for="blue">blue</label>
                            </li>
                            <li>&nbsp;</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content__size size">
                    <h3 class="size__caption">Select the size</h3>
                    <div class="size__slider">
                        <div class="size__handle"></div>
                        <span>small</span>
                        <span>large</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content__feedback feedback">
                    <h3 class="feedback__caption">Your feedback</h3>
                    <div class="feedback__hint">How can we improve ...</div>
                    <div class="feedback__lines">
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <input id="l0" type="text" placeholder=" ..." maxlength="77" value="Colors panel is ..." class="l0" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <span>
                                <input id="l1" type="text" placeholder="..." maxlength="77" value="" class="l1" />
                            </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="content__response response">
                    <h3 class="response__caption">How to send our response</h3>
                    <div class="response__hint">Do you prefer email or mobile?</div>
                    <div>
                        <span>
                            <input type="radio" name="response" value="email" id="email" class="response__email" />
                            <label for="email">email</label>
                        </span>
                        <span>
                            <input type="radio" name="response" value="Mobile" id="Mobile" class="response__Mobile" />
                            <label for="Mobile">Mobile</label>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </main>
            <footer class="footer">
                <div class="footer__date date">
                    <label for="date">Date if writing</label>
                    <div>
                        <input id="date-date" type="date" pattern="dd-MM-yyyy" title="date..."
                         min="1000-01-01" max="3000-12-31" value="25-08-2017" class="date__input-date" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Также, стоит ли добавлять ARIA?

Comment: `main role="main"` — масло масляное

Comment: А есть дизайн с которого верстаете?

Comment: @AlexanderBragin https://hostingkartinok.com/show-image.php?id=5c016113892cb402401ae4f792a282e7